# Does EF6 virtual navigation property result into SQL query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

Assuming that I have an entity with virtual nagivation property like this:

```
public class School
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Students> Students { get; set; }
}
```

As I understand, EF6 uses proxy to enable lazy-loading of `Students`, but do the following LINQ queries:

```
var myStudent = this.Students.Single(x => x.Id == id);
var studentsCount = this.Students.Count();
var bestStudents = this.Students
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.GPA)
    .Take(5)
    .ToArray();
```

result into a SQL query (just like `IQueryable<T>` does)? Or is it just a lazy-loading collection and will load all students into memory after the first request, and then perform simple `IEnumerable<T>` LINQ behaviour?

Comment: It depends... You really shouldn't have your entity classes have that additional code in though - you will likely have issues if you try to access the students collections, particularly if the context has been disposed later on.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you! My question sounded too broad :) I have edited it out.

Comment: What is "this" in the second code fragment?

Answer (score 1):

When you query for an entity in Entity Framework, the objects that get returned are not (always) the type of object you think they are.  Behind the scenes, it creates a brand new class that inherits from the your class.  Because OOP allows a subclass to be stored in a variable typed as the superclass, you never really notice.  This is the "proxy" that you mention.  That's why the `virtual` function allows lazy loading.  The subclass overrides your virtual method, and contains the code to lazy load the extra data before returning it.

That overridden property call will then check the context to see if the navigation properties are already loaded.  If they are, it just returns them.  If they are not, it will make additional SQL calls to load them, storing them in the `DbContext` for later.

---

In your updated question, my understanding is that running those lines of code would result in 3 separate queries being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Public virtual properties are lazy loading in EF6. 
You can disable lazy loading for a DbContext, or use the .Include() method on the IQueryable to include the property in the first query.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Once you "iterate" through the list (e.g. by calling the .Single(), .Count() or .ToArray() method), the query is executed and you have a in-memory list of your students. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution for more details about query execution.

The first example would result in 3 queries, where the first returns the student with the given Id, the second returns the student count and the third returns the first 5 students ordered desc by their GPA property.

Regarding DDD => You can use some Layered architecture, with ApplicationServices and DomainServices, where DomainServices perform the domain logic and ApplicationServices load / transform the data.

The https://aspnetboilerplate.com/ template is for example a good starting point for domain driven design.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the second code block is executed somewhere INSIDE the scope of an instance of 'School' (so 'this' is an instance of 'School' - in my example below school19) then the following scenarios are possible:

A) You have loaded your instance of 'School' like this (Lazy loading enabled):

```
var school19 = dbContext.Set<School>()
 .FirstOrDefault(school => school.Id == 19)
```

Then your 3 lines of code for accessing the property 'Students' will trigger a single additional database hit when

```
var myStudent = this.Students.Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

is executed, but no more database hits will occur with the subsequent two statements.

B) In case you have loaded your instance of 'School' like this (Lazy loading enabled):

```
var school19 = dbContext.Set<School>()
 .Include(school => school.Students)
 .FirstOrDefault(school => school.Id == 19)
```

Then your 3 lines of code for accessing the property 'Students' will not trigger an additional database hit.

C) If lazy loading was disabled, then

- A) would result in a Null Reference Exception
- B) would behave the same

---

As a last remark, if 'this' was a reference to an instance of the DBContext class, which has a property

```
public Set<School> Schools { get; set; }
```

then it would trigger 3 different database calls. But the result is different as this would be executed in the context of ALL schools, while my assumptions above only apply to a single school.

Comment: Why does `var bestStudents = this.Students.OrderByDescending(x => x.GPA).Take(5).ToArray();` not trigger an additional database hit, if you query for a single Id? I have to test this, but i don't think that EF can cache anything from the previous call there, because there is an OrderByDescending in the query.

Comment: As soon as you access the lazy loaded property, it will trigger a database call to resolve the Students and assign the list to the property. Subsequent use of the property will be in memory as you have loaded them all. This is in  my opinion also the reason (and a problem) for lazy loading. Imagine you have a school with 10,000 pupils, as soon as you access the property you will load 10,000 rows from the database.